# Does the Zener diode in this schematic need a current limiting resistor?

Tags: zener, mosfet-driver, p-channel

This is a fairly generic P-Channel MOSFET driver. The supply voltage is 12 - 48 V. The Zener used is a BZX84-C12. Would this Zener diode need a current limiting resistor of, say, 1 kiloohm between `SUP+` and its cathode?

[image]

Comment: The resistor should go in the node connecting the 10K pullup and the zener *anode* /gate.

Comment: Something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/1YzIvEk.png)? If this is correct, can you please explain how this works?

Comment: That would limit the Zener current but do little to clamp the gate-source voltage. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the given schematic, any supply voltage above the Zener voltage would allow a unlimited amount of current to flow when the opto-coupler is conducting, possibly damaging the Zener and the opto-coupler.

The purpose of the Zener is to clamp the MOSFET's gate-source voltage. Most MOSFET's have a maximum Vgs of +/-20V, so 48V is certainly too much. Placing a resistor between `SUP+` and the Zener cathode would limit the current but would do nothing in order to clamp the MOSFET Vgs.

In stead, the resistor should go between the MOSFET gate/Zener anode junction and the opto-coupler.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGPep5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. The value of R1 then would be (SUP - Vzener)/Iz?

Comment: @electrophile The MOSFET has a maximum Vgs of +/-20V. Say you want to start clamping with a proper Zener current of 1mA @ 18V then `(18V - 12V) / 1mA = 6K`. Closest E12 is 5K6. At 48V that dissipates 230mW in the Zener so I'd upgrade to a 500mW device.

Answer (score 0):

The [LTV-817S](https://optoelectronics.liteon.com/upload/download/DS-70-96-0016/LTV-8X7%20series%20201610%20.PDF) has a maximum collector current of 50 mA and a maximum power dissipation of 200 mW so I'd be very concerned that with an applied voltage greater than about 12 volts, this device could be damaged.

> *Does the zener diode in this schematic need a current limiting
> resistor?*

Not only to prevent damage to itself but to protect the LTV-817S device.

Comment: Thanks. Something like [this](https://i.imgur.com/1YzIvEk.png) then?

Comment: No, put it in series with pin 4 or pin 3 of the opto.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you likely need a current limiting resistor. The LTV-817S has a current transfer ratio that is only specified to be > 0.5. So, even with a defined input current, only the minimum output current is defined.

A 1 k resistor would be too low to use. The current would approach (48-10)/1k = 38 mA, and the power would be well over 1 W in it. A larger resistance (say 4.7k) would conduct much less current and power dissipation would be about 1/3 W. For long term reliability you probably need at least a ½ W resistor.

Note the 10 k isn't very critical, and is mostly needed to counteract any leakage in the optocoupler (max. 100 nA), as well as generate a reasonable turn-off rate for the FET. 10 k is reasonable.

Note the optocoupler output is only rated to 35 V. That would be exceeded when the supply is 48 V. You should find a better rated device.